# How to detect incoming call is a forwarded call?

Tags: calls, nexus-5

I want to know if the incoming call is a forwarded call when my Nexus 5 is ringing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Forwarded Call Alert Free ROOT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.duenndns.forwardedcall.free&hl=en). It also has a [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.duenndns.forwardedcall&hl=en), and an [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=787706).

*There may also be other apps that can do this that I may not be aware of.*

Comment: Doesn't work on my N5